# How can i solve the error of 'var' in ASP.Net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var query2 =  from cm in DC.custMasts where cm.custCity == TextBox1.Text.Trim()_ select cm.custName, custCity, custCompany;     
        GridView1.DataSource  = query2 ;
}
```

I'm getting error

> CS0819: Implicitly-typed local variables cannot have multiple declarators

How can i solve this error?

EDIT :: Thank you guys, it worked and error disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   var query2 =  from cm in DC.custMasts 
                 where cm.custCity == TextBox1.Text.Trim()
                 select new 
                 {
                     Name=cm.custName, 
                     City=cm.cmcustCity, 
                     Company=cm.custCompany
                 }.ToList();

   GridView1.DataSource  = query2 ;   
   GridView1.DataBind();     
}
```

Comment: 'Ghost Answer' - by name, by nature ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new object in the select part of the linq query:

```
var query2 =  from cm in DC.custMasts where cm.custCity == TextBox1.Text.Trim()_
              select new {
                  Name = cm.custName,
                  City = custCity,
                  Company = custCompany
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var query2 =  from cm in DC.custMasts where cm.custCity == TextBox1.Text.Trim()
     select new {
               Name=cm.custName, 
               City=cm.cmcustCity, 
               Company=cm.custCompany
               }.ToList();

  GridView1.DataSource  = query2 ;
  GridView1.DataBind();
```